# Change set with permission set fails due to dependent permissions?

Tags: deployment, change-set, permission-sets

I've built a change set that includes a permission set and it's failing in production saying it needs read access to a parent object. When I look in the source org, the permission set includes read access to the object.

I know with profiles you only get the permissions for the objects in the change set, so even if you'd set a permission on an object, you can get an error on deployment if that perm is required and the object isn't in the change set. However, I'd thought permission sets were included wholesale and didn't have to deal with this? What am I missing?

In my specific scenario, we have `account`->`child1__c`->`child2__c`, each related by master-detail. The permission set includes full perms on `child2__c`, and read perms on both account and `child1__c`. The change set includes object `child2__c`, but not `child1__c`. The error is `Permission Create MyPermissionSet__c depends on permission(s): Read child1__c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not wholesale upload of the permission set. It follows the same rules as the migration tool. Only objects and fields in the change set are uploaded. This allows partial updates to profiles and permission sets. You must include all appropriate entities, even if they're not changing directly.

Comment: Thanks, was worried about that. Should just stick to my current adage of don't do anything permission related with change sets (or metadata api for that matter), I just can't get over deploying stuff that someone else might have touched unbeknownst to me. Hopefully they'll figure out permission deployment some day ...